# Forcing the left-to-right order in all buffers

Tags: bidirectional-support

How can I force all the letters go left to right including the characters from right-to-left languages in all buffers? Currently it displays the lines with right-to-left characters bidirectionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bidi reordering is controlled by the buffer-local variable `bidi-paragraph-direction`.  You make it default to L2R by adding the following incantation to your init file:

```
(setq-default bidi-paragraph-direction 'left-to-right)
```

---

(There is also `bidi-display-reordering`, but that can lead to crashes and [should *not* be changed unless you're debugging Emacs itself](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-07/msg00294.html).)